# How to right or left shift function on a semi-logarithmic scale?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am reading a paper where the horizontal shift of sigmoidal functions is explained by the division of the function by a constant. Here the functions:

[image: Shifted sigmoids on semi-log scale]

I assume that this is the case because the data is plotted on a semi-log scale, as else functions are horizontally shifted either with adding or subtracting a constant from $x$: $f(x+a)$ or $f(x-a)$.

So my question is, why is this shift achieved by division on a semi-log scale?

[Original paper](https://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/courses/perceptionGrad/Readings/Carandini-NRN2012.pdf), the posted plot corresponds to Figure 2b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the horizontal axis, to move one unit to the right you multiply by $100$.  On a standard scale you add one unit to move one unit to the right.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense! Is there a way to formalize that though? Say we have f(x+a) and write it on a semi-logarithmic axis, where does the multiplication formally come from?

Comment: The point is that you are plotting the log of the argument, not the argument itself.  To move one unit in the log you multiply by the base, so you have $f(ax)$ which gets plotted at $\log a + \log x$ and $\log a$ is the offset.